# Using fuzz parameter with perlmagick in compare api

Tags: perl, imagemagick

I am trying to use perlmagick to compare 2 images. It works perfectly fine for most of the cases, but if there is slight difference in pixels then it is counted as error.
If I use compare command provided by ImageMagick then I can specify fuzz parameter which will treat pixels in the given distance as same.

I tried using fuzz option in compare api as suggested in documentation but it's not working.
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php

`$Difference = $orgImage->Compare(
                image   => $secondImage,
                metric  => 'RMSE',
                fuzz => '100',
                channel => 'ALL'
                );`

Thanks !

Comment: Please clarify "it's not working" with details of what is wrong?

Comment: I do not see any effect of fuzz value on output (difference in images)

Comment: So you are using the difference image for visual cues on where the changes are, and need the output image from `Compare` directly?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue in PerlMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=13536) which hasn't been fixed since its discovery in 2009, it would seem that the `Compare()` function internally uses an equality operation rather than a comparison operation. Maybe call the CLI utility from in your perl script?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $difference = `compare -metric RMSE -fuzz 15% first.png second.png null: 2>&1`;
my $diffAmount = $difference =~ m/\([\d.]*\)/;

if ($diffAmount == 0) {
    print "Yay\n";
}
```

Comment: Tried with 0.1 but still it's not working. Tried various combinations as well.

Comment: @NikhilWalvekar Did some digging and apparently [it's a known issue in PerlMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=13536). Maybe call the shell utility in-line?

Comment: @NikhilWalvekar I've added an example of calling the CLI utility inline.

Comment: I tried using CLI, output image is getting affected due to fuzz parameter but the error returned is not changing with fuzz parameter.
`>compare -fuzz 15% -channel ALL -metric rmse file1.png file2.png diff.png

114.324 (0.00174448)

>compare -channel ALL -metric rmse file1.png file2.png diff.png

114.324 (0.00174448)`

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the issue of fuzz not working by extracting error data from the difference image. Here is a routine I have used in comparison tests.

```
sub cmp_image {
    my ( $result_img, $expect_img, $max_error, $test_name ) = @_;

    my $difference_img = $expect_img->Compare( 
       image => $result_img,
       metric=>'rmse' );

    ok( $difference_img->Get('error') < $max_error, $test_name )
        or diag "Error metric: " . $difference_img->Get('error');
}
```

Unfortunately, this approach does not help you if you want to view the locations of errors, as even smallest differences between the images will be drawn in `$difference_img`.